# How to create a counter with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a for loop that will iterate through and for each unique ID will calculate the time spent in each SubmissionStatus(e.g. pending OSPA, Pending Department) and store the results in a list of dictionaries where each dictionary corresponds to each unique ID. The time spent is calculated by taking the earliest LastModified value while the status is in a particular phase and subtracting that value from the LastModified value when the status changes to the next phase (when SubmissionStatus goes from Pending OSPA to Pending Department, I would take the LastModified timestamp from the row and subtract the lowest Last Modified timestamp when SubmissionStatus is Pending OSPA e.g. 04/05/2018-04/01/2018=4 days + 04/06/2018-04/05/2018=1 day so total = 5 days )

input is a pandas dataframe:

```
    ID  LastModified    SubmissionStatus
0   1   04/01/2018      Pending OSPA
1   1   04/03/2018      Pending OSPA
2   1   04/05/2018      Pending Department
3   1   04/06/2018      Pending OSPA
4   2   04/02/2018      Pending OSPA
5   2   04/03/2018      Pending Department
6   2   04/05/2018      Complete
```

output is a list of dictionaries:

```
[
 { ID : 1,
   DaysWithOSPA: 5,
   DaysWithDepartment: 1},
 { ID : 2,
   DaysWithOSPA:1
   DaysWithDepartment:2}]
```

Comment: Please show the exact output you want to get. The output you posted here is very symbolic. It's also unclear what your input is. Is it a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Aran-Fey! I updated the output. It is a list of dictionaries with a dictionary for each unique ID number. The input is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'SubmissionStatus']).sum()
```

Comment: I need a total of the time spent in each Submission Status not the sum of times the id is in the status.